# how can we import a content from a database into another database by writing command in a SQL file in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql-9.3, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

how can I move data from one to another with command not with import/export?

Answer (score 0):

How much data? You could set up a view in your local database to a table in the remote database using dblink. Then query the view.